# How do I add a paragraph's width with each click with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to add width to my paragraph with each click with Javascript. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code :

```js
let button = document.querySelector("button");

    button.addEventListener("click",function(e) {

    let p = document.querySelector("p");
    if(window.getComputedStyle(p).getPropertyValue("width")==="10px")
    {
        p.style.width = "10px";
        p++;
    }
    else 
    {
        console.log(false)
    }
});
```

```css
p {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgb(0,0,0,0.4);
    height: 40px;
    width: 10px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<button>click!</button>
<p>my paragraph</p>
```

Comment: What is the intended result of clicking the button supposed to be? The code you have right now doesn't really give me an idea of what you want to happen? How much wider should it get on each click? Is there a point where it should stop getting wider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if condition is wrong, since you want to change the `width` with every click. Once you click the first time, you `width` will be `20px` so the condition won't be met again. You want instead to check if the `width` is of a certain value.

> Notice that I am checking `var widthValue` because it
>   seems I cannot check the value of `p.style.width`

```js
var widthValue = 10;

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var p = document.querySelector("p");

    if(widthValue < 100) {
        p.style.width = `${widthValue}px` ;
    }
    widthValue += 10;
});
```

```css
p {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgb(0,0,0,0.4);
    height: 40px;
    width: 10px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<button>click!</button>
<p>my paragraph</p>
```

Comment: You can use let style = getComputedStyle(p) to get access to all of p's styles, and then use style.width to access the width (but it's read only)

Answer (score 0):

This should create the desired effect that I think you were looking for. I got rid of the if statement and instead made it so whenever the button is clicked it increases the left margin by 1px. Changing the width wouldn't work because that changes the size of the paragraph block and not it's position.

```js
 let button = document.querySelector("button");
 let width = 0;
 button.onclick = function(){
    width ++;
    var p = document.querySelector("p");
    p.style = `margin-left:${width}px;`;
 };
```

```css
p {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgb(0,0,0,0.4);
    height: 40px;
    width: 10px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<button>click!</button>
<p>my paragraph</p>
```